# Search for folder with parents set in google drive api

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I want to search for folder in google drive, but I need to deal with case that folder doesn't have parent.

```
$file = $this->service->files->listFiles(
                                array('q' =>  
                                       "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' 
                                        and trashed = false 
                                        and name = '".$name."' 
                                        and '".$parent."' in parents" ));
```

I don't know how to set last parameter, according to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters) it should be like that, but when parent is NULL it doesn't return anything.

Comment: All files have parents root is the parent of everything.   I don't think I understand what you are trying to do.   Search for a folder in drive all you should need is mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'  and name = 'test'

Comment: Your answer helped, thanks! I swear I tried 'root' before but maybe without quote marks. And I need to search inside a folder, because I am creating subfolders with same name, so I need to find a folder that belongs to it parent folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All files have parents root is the parent of everything. I don't think I understand what you are trying to do. Search for a folder in drive all you should need is mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name = 'test'

Tip:

Use string format to avoid issues with your quotes.

```
string.Format("mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed = false and name = '{0}' and '{1}' in parents",name,parent  )
```